# How can I change the Windows 10 login picture from the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

How can I change the Windows 10 login picture from the command line? I know you can do this from the settings, but how can you do it from the command line?

Comment: Do you mean the background image or the user profile icon?

Comment: @Narzard I mean the background image on the login screen